# Can't merge daily sentiment score with daily price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I have the tweets from Twitter and transformed them into daily sentiment scores with Vadar and Pivot table. And I have the price of a stock for the same period of time and I transformed it into a dataframe by `price_df = price.to_frame()`.

Now I want to do merge them into one DF (should be okay because they have the same index?)

I tried this `merge = pd.concat([price_df,pivot],axis = 1)` this would show the adjusted close price and but not the sentiment compound score:

```
merge:       Adj Close  (mean, compound)
Date                                   
2016-06-13  30.560539               NaN
2016-06-14  29.176666               NaN
2016-06-15        NaN               NaN
```

But with `axis = 0`, it shows the mean compound but not the sentiment score:

```
merge:             Adj Close  (mean, compound)
Date                                   
2016-06-13        NaN          0.110393
2016-06-14        NaN         -0.093310
2016-06-15        NaN         -0.194588
```

Also tried the `merge = pivot.merge(price_df, on = 'Date')`, it shows an error:

`You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat` but this goes back to the first two attempts..`.

the two data frames are as follow:

```
print(price_df.dtypes)
print('price: ' + str(price_df.tail(3)))`
Adj Close    float64
dtype: object
price:             Adj Close
Date                 
2016-06-10  31.848307
2016-06-13  30.560539
2016-06-14  29.176666`

print(pivot.dtypes)
print('pivot: '+ str(pivot))`
mean  compound    float64
dtype: object
pivot:                 mean
            compound
Date                
2016-03-10  0.073948
2016-03-11  0.186440
2016-03-12  0.033318
2016-03-13  0.212868
2016-03-14  0.191440
...              ...
2016-06-11  0.060406
2016-06-12  0.040659
2016-06-13  0.110393
2016-06-14 -0.093310
2016-06-15 -0.194588`
```

sorry for the poor structure, this is the first time I ask on Stack

---

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: But it seems you need `pivot.index = pd.to_datetime(pivot.index)` first

Comment: @jezrael a genius at work. Mind sharing why do I need that? I am new to python

Comment: Sure, for merging by concat or merge need same types of data for merging, so need both datetimes or both objects. For perfornace is better convert both to datetimes.